# How do I change the difficulty on a save file?

Tags: dead-space

Long story short, I started a new game on Hard (after installing the game and playing it for the first time in my life), quit the game, started it again, loaded my save (still saying hard), tried saving again, and the file says that the difficulty is "Normal". I overwrite it, open the save terminal again, and it still says "Normal".

I'm now on chapter 3, and all previous saves were on the "Normal" difficulty? So, how do I crank it up? (Also, it's on Steam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been playing Dead Space on hard, but suddenly it decided to change to easy... seems I stumbled over the continue glitch! Anyway, I've found a way how to change back to your original difficulty.
>
> Start hex workshop and open up your savegame, after you made a backup (folder: users\xxxx\Documents\Electronic Arts\Dead Space). Rightclick, select GoTo and enter 00001062. Change the text to the difficulty you would like to have. This will probably only change the label on the save, therefore go to line 00002061 and change the number after diff to: 0 for easy, 1 for normal, 2 for hard. Save
>
> I hope this helps people that run in this problem...

--Courtesy of sugarcube666 From [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/949616-dead-space/48157615)

Comment: Nope. No "difficulty" under "options".

Comment: @user1337 Please look at the edit to the answer. Also you have an awesome username.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I'mma try this thingie out once I beat Leviathan (at least on medium, eh?)

Comment: Nice! Good Luck!